# How to send a BytesIO like file object (sound) to API telegram bot using a python requests?

Tags: https, python-requests, telegram, python-requests-html

Can't send. Through the python-telegram-bot library, the data is sent ok. But I have to send it in a few places synchronously.

This is a working code for sending text messages:

```
def send_text_msg(_chat_id: int, text: str) -> None:
    token = TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN
    chat_id = str(_chat_id)
    url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token + "/sendMessage" + "?chat_id=" + 
chat_id + "&text=" + text
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
        # print(response.json())
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
        print('Error fetching response using requests')
```

And this code doesn't work, this is what I want:

```
def send_voice_msg(chat_id: int, voice_file: BytesIO) -> None:
    token = TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN
    url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token + "/sendMessage"
    data = {"chat_id": chat_id, "caption": 'voice.ogg'},
    files = {'voice': voice_file}
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}

    r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data, files=files, timeout=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a working code.

```
def send_voice_msg(chat_id: int, voice_file: BytesIO) -> None:
    token = TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN
    url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token + "/sendVoice" + "?chat_id=" + str(chat_id) + "&voice="
    file = {'voice': ('voice.ogg', voice_file)}
    try:
        post = requests.post(url, files=file, timeout=3)
        logger.info(f'voice message status code is {post.status_code}')
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
        logger.warning('Error fetching response using requests')
```